# MySQL Replication, Can i add a trigger to the SLAVE db?

Tags: mysql, replication, trigger

Is it possible to do so? The trigger will insert some rows into a unique table that exists only on the slave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is it possible to do so? The trigger will insert some rows into a unique table that exists only on the slave."

yes, you can

A lot of warehousing architectures are based on the slave only.

The title of your question is wrong. Change replica DB with SLAVE ONLY

Comment: Trigger on slave are executed with statement-based replication. See [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-features-triggers.html)

Comment: he is not asking that